# Modx formit working in one site - not working in another

Tags: modx, formit

I have a form and formit call that works in one site and not another, which is a direct copy of the first [migrating to a new design] The sites are identical right now, files & database were just copied. All the plugins were checked and even reinstalled.

What I have is:

```
<!-- contact page -->
[[!FormIt? 
    &placeholderPrefix=`contact.` 
    &hooks=`spam,email,redirect,FormItAutoResponder` 
    &emailTo=`[[GetSystemSetting? &setting=`emailContactMailTo`]]` 
    &emailSubject=`domain.com Contact form has been submitted. [[+contact.subject]]` 
    &emailTpl=`ContactCustomEmailTpl` 
    &redirectTo=`346` 
    &emailReplyTo=`no-reply@domain.com`
    &submitVar=`contactSubmit`
    &validate=`name:required,email:email:required,subject:required,text:required:stripTags` 
    &fiarSubject=`Your contact request to domain.com` 
    &fiarTpl=`ContactCustomEmailTpl` 
    &fiarReplyTo=`no-reply@domain.com` 
]]
    <form class="form" action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post"  role="form">
        <input type="hidden" name="nospam:blank" value="" />

        <div class="row">

            [[!+contact.error_message:notempty=`<div class="col-sm-12"><div class="alert alert-danger">[[!+contact.error_message]]</div></div>`]]

            <div class="col-sm-4[[+contact.error.name:notempty=` has-error`]]">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name"> Name: *</label>
                    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="[[!+contact.name]]" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4[[+contact.error.email:notempty=` has-error`]]">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email"> Email: *</label>
                <input id="email" type="text" name="email" value="[[!+contact.email]]" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4[[+contact.error.subject:notempty=` has-error`]]">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject"> Subject: *</label>
                <input id="subject" type="text" name="subject" value="[[!+contact.subject]]" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-12[[+contact.error.text:notempty=` has-error`]]">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="text"> Message: *</label>
                <textarea id="text" name="text" rows="7" class="form-control">[[!+contact.text]]</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label> </label>
                <input class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="contactSubmit" value="Send Contact Inquiry"  onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ContactPage', 'Contact Submitted']);" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </form>

</div>
```

The form will work if I remove the 'FormItAutoResponder' from the &hooks AND all items from the &validate parameters.

What is wrong with this form?

- no usefull errors in modx or server logs
- reinstalled formit
- isolated it in a test page with no other markup
- the emailTpl is present and mail gets sent if the 2 parameters are removed from the formit call

Comment: are the sites on the same server?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the GetSystemSetting snippet is missing? Why not just use `[[++emailContactMailTo]]` instead?

Are the MODX and FormIt versions the same on both sites?

Try calling [this debug snippet](http://pastebin.com/r6Sk5Tac) somewhere below the FormIt call. Look for unshown errors (starting with contact.error.) or any other unexpected placeholders.